# Need help on SQL Server report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a question on SQL Server Reporting Services. In fact, I want to know about how to make a particular logic work.

I have a main report which has one sub-report inside it. The report takes an input parameter `test_id` and accordingly displays the data in tabular form.

When the `test_id` has a valid value that's matching, it displays the data.

But, when `test_id` doesn't have a valid value and hence it doesn't match, I get the empty table as below.

```
TESTNAME   TESTDETAIL  

Sub-report

TESTPARENTID PARENT DETAILS
```

I want to know how to display a message "No details found for the test_id" INSTEAD of displaying any empty tables. Only title and subtitle should display.

Answer (score 3):

Objects like Tablix in SSRS have a property `NoRowsMessage`.

[image]

You can set this to display a message if there are zero rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to go into the tablix properties. Under Visibility, select Show or hide based on an expression. You can write an expression here to hide the entire tablix. Just change the name of the field to match yours:

```
=iif(Count(Field1)=0,True,False)
```

Comment: Any someone please help me on how to paste a portion of screenprint or image to show clearly my issue. I will highly appreciate any guidance

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the suggestion.With this in mind and little tweaking it worked  =iif(Count(Fields!Testid.Value)=0,True,False).

But,now the issue is when No Data is displayed,I want to print a message that "No Data present or displayed"

**One thing,the No rows functionality doesnot work as given earlier.

Thanks again
Rexian

Comment: Add a textbox right after the table with the "no rows" message you want. Give it the opposite visibility settings so that you will just get one or the other.